# Two FK's pointing to the same column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int RepresentativeId { get; set; }
   public int ChargeRepresentativeId { get; set; }
}

public class Representative
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Every Customer has its own Representative represented with `RepresentativeId` column, but also in certain scenarios I want to create new `Customer` with both `RepresentativeId` and its `ChargeRepresentativeId`.

I already have a FK constraint applied on `RepresentativeId` column

```
ALTER TABLE [Representatives] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_Representatives] 
FOREIGN KEY([RepresentativeId]) REFERENCES [Representative] ([Id])
```

How can I force `ChargeRepresentativeId` to be valid data which exists in the `Representatives` table (the case I already have for the `RepresentativeId`)?

Comment: following isn't working?
ALTER TABLE [Representatives] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_Representatives] 
FOREIGN KEY([RepresentativeId]) REFERENCES [Representative] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [Representatives] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Customers_ChargeRepresentatives] 
FOREIGN KEY([ChargeRepresentativeId]) REFERENCES [Representative] ([Id])

Comment: nope, tried already. I'm getting `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Customers_Representatives". ... The conflict occurred in database "...", table "Representatives", column 'Id'`.

Comment: That error means that you have data in that table that would not be valid if you created the new foreign key constraint. It means you need to update your existing data before you can create the new foreign key constraint.

Comment: How do you mean I need to update the data? The data in the Representatives table is valid, If I understood you adding another FK will work if I start from scratch with no data?

Comment: @user1765862 - That error means that there is data in the referencing table (in your case Customer, specifically the ChargeRepresentativeId) that points to an invalid row in the referenced table (in your case, Representative). Doing something like `select c.ID, c.ChargeRepresentativeId from dbo.Customer as c left join dbo.Representative as r on r.ID = c.ChargeRepresentativeId  where r.ID is null` should identify the offending data.